# javascript error message is not showing up

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an error if the textbox (First_Name) is left empty. For example, if the firstname field is left empty, the user will receive the following error: "Please enter your first name" Nothing happens when I click the submit button after leaving the field blank though...

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>this is a test page</TITLE>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function CheckForm()
{
  var formObj = document.getElementById("Data");
  var firstname = formObj.FIRST_Name.value;

    if(notEmpty(firstname, "Please enter your first name")){                        

    return true;}

    return false;
    }

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
    if(elem.value.length == 0){
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div style="background: #CCCC99">
<HR><FORM id="Data" onsubmit="return CheckForm()" >
<P>First Name: <input type=text name=FIRST_Name maxlength=15 size=15>
</P>
<input type=submit value="Submit Products Registration Form" style="width: 220px"><input type=reset value="Reset">
</form>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstname` is the elements value but you pass it to `notEmpty` as an element, instead use

```
if(notEmpty(formObj.FIRST_Name, "Please enter your first name")){
```